# Заполнение формы на сайте через post request в python

Tags: python, post, requests

Пытаюсь сделать заполнение формы на сайте через пост запрос в Python. (сайт взял как пример)

```
import requests
datas = {
    'username':'def',
    'password1':'def',
    'password2':'def',
    'email':'def'
    }

username = input('username: ')
password1 = input('password1: ')
password2 = input('password2: ')
email = input('email: ')

datas['username'] = username
datas['password1'] = password1
datas['password2'] = password2
datas['email'] = email

url = 'https://leetcode.com/accounts/signup'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'
    }
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
    csrf_token = r.cookies['csrftoken']
    print(csrf_token)
    datas['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrf_token
    loging = s.post(url, data = datas, headers = headers)
    print(loging.status_code)
    print(loging.text)
```

Получаю ошибку: **CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.**

При этом CSRF я передаю. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: А вы точно хотите создать создать аккаунт с помощью скрипта а не залогиниться на сайт?

Comment: Какого результата вы в результате хотите достичь?

Comment: Вообще я литкод для примера взял.

Задание: заполнять на сайте с вакансиями поля из бд и отправлять.

Comment: Если Вы хотите визуально эффекта, то используйте `selenium`. Просто для каждого ресурса и задачи способы могут сильно отличаться. Если хотите получить решение для конкретной задачи, лучше в примерах использовать конкретные ссылки на ресурсы для которых вы собираетесь применять код